# Linear Activation Function in Neural Network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

[Graph of output vs. weighted sum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpiX1.jpg)
The linear activation function $$ z = b+\sum_{i=0}^k x_iw_i $$
Is used in simple linear neurons in a neural network. Graphs of the *z v.* the weighted sum of the inputs plus the bias show the line passing through (0, 0), the origin. Is this a strict requirement? Can the line not pass through the origin?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a strict requirement for activation functions in general, but for the simple linear neuron it is. For instance, with the sigmoid activation function, we typically have a $y$-intercept of $1/2$, but for a linear activation $0$ is typical.

Comment: So it's mostly a matter of convention?